# Parsing rainbow tables outputting error I'm not understanding

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm creating a parser for rainbow tables and want to read 1024 bytes of the file to decide what the file is split by, be it `: ; . ,` or white space. However, when I try to find the parser in the file I'm getting an error stating `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`. My best guess is that the error is coming from this line, `for item in table.read(1024):` but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
def is_valid_table(tablename):
    possible_parsers = [";", ".", ":", ","]
    with open(tablename) as table:
        if possible_parsers not in table.read():
            raise EnvironmentError(
                "Your rainbow table does not contain the correct parsers "
                "valid parser are '{}'. Refractor your rainbow table and try "
                "parsing it once more.".format(possible_parsers)
            )
        else:
            for item in table.read(1024):
                for parser in possible_parsers:
                    if parser in item:
                        return parser
```

Comment: You shouldn't guess as the error message also gives you the number of the erroneous line. Spoiler: the error doesn't come from the line you think it comes from.

Comment: No, the problem is `if possible_parsers not in table.read():` - `possible_parsers` is a list, which isn't something that can meaningfully be contained in a string.

Comment: @jasonharper That makes sense, thank you